# Call Variables from List in Loop in R

Tags: r, object, paste

I have variables named var1, var2, ... var100 in data. **How can I call them in a loop?** I can loop over them and get the names as strings like this:

```
for (i in c(sprintf("data$var%s",seq(1,100)))) {
  print(paste0(i))
}
```

But this gives me only the strings, and does not call the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i in c(sprintf("var%s",seq(1,100)))) {
  print(data[, i])
}
```